# Idiomatic way to do basic pattern matching on multiple variables in Python

Tags: python, pattern-matching, idioms

I want to achieve what this code (written in Crystal) does:

```
enum PieceKind
    Pawn, Rook, Bishop, Knight, King, Queen
end

def piece_kind_at_init(x, y)
    case y
    when 2, 7 then PieceKind::Pawn
    when 1, 8
        case x
        when 1, 8 then PieceKind::Rook
        when 2, 7 then PieceKind::Bishop
        when 3, 6 then PieceKind::Knight
        when 4 then PieceKind::King
        when 5 then PieceKind::Queen
        end
    end
end
```

This is the "nicest" version I was able to come up with in Python:

```
class PieceKind(Enum):
    Pawn = auto()
    Rook = auto()
    Bishop = auto()
    Knight = auto()
    King = auto()
    Queen = auto()

def piece_kind_at_init(x, y):
    if y in [2, 7]:     
        return PieceKind.Pawn
    elif y in [1, 8]:
        if x in [1, 8]:     
            return PieceKind.Rook
        elif x in [2, 7]:   
            return PieceKind.Bishop
        elif x in [3, 6]:   
            return PieceKind.Knight
        elif x == 4:        
            return PieceKind.King
        elif x == 5:        
            return PieceKind.Queen
```

It's fine, but it's definitely less readable the version with proper pattern matching. What's the most idiomatic way to write the code?

Comment: If you're looking for a `switch` statement, python doesn't have those - `elif` chains as you've written them are the way to go.

Comment: Alternantively, you might just define all your y = 1 pieces in a `list` as so:

`[Piecekind.Rook, Piecekind.Knight, Piecekind.Bishop, ...]`

Comment: Since this question is about style/Pythonic idioms, you may be interested in the reasoning behind this: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python

Answer (score 0):

One way to get rid of lengthy `elif` chain is to create a translation table.

```
outer_row_pieces = [PieceKind.Rook,
                    PieceKind.Knight,
                    PieceKind.Bishop,
                    PieceKind.King,
                    PieceKind.Queen,
                    PieceKind.Bishop,
                    Piecekind.Knight,
                    PieceKind.Rook]

def piece_kind_at_init(x, y):
    if y == 2 or y == 7:
        return PieceKind.Pawn
    if y == 1 or y == 8:
        return outer_row_pieces[x]
    return None
```